# jquery swap content make page default on load

Tags: jquery, default, onload

I need con1 to show active and be loaded onload  of page.

this is my code to swap content. I am using a external php page to swap out content when the id of con1 con2 and so on our clicked.

I want to make con1 show onload of page and the link to show active but when you go to the page it only shows my div with no content till a link is clicked. once link is clicked it hovers shows active and works great.

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.topnav").click(function() {
        $("a.topnav.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});

function swapContent(cv) {
    var url = "content.php";
    $.post(url,{contentVar: cv},function(data){
        $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show your html?  What is con1/con2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `class="active"` to the link for con1 that needs to be active when the page loads.

Comment: but then when you click link 2 link 1 will stay active

Comment: It shouldn't, but unless I can see your code I can't really help much more.  If you post your html or create a fiddle, we'll be able to solve this quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If everything works great after you click on the link, why not trigger the click event on `$(document).ready`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.topnav").click(function() {
        $("a.topnav.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $("#link1").click(); //trigger click
});
```